# Simple JSON-RPC in C++ for embedded platforms?

Tags: c++, json, embedded, json-rpc

The desired key-feature for me is the ability to register functions of objects to the JSON-RPC server task, which then calls the function, in case the respective JSON-RPC-call was received.

How can this be done?

I found https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp , but the concept of the stub-generator looks a bit overdone to me.

Comment: In RPC, the alternative to a stub generator is writing stubs by hand. That gets boring quickly.

Comment: I agree with @RichardHodges. gSOAP works the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libjson-rpc-cpp does not require you to use the stub generator. You can always create the bindings manually.

Additional C++ frameworks for JSON-RPC can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=JSON-RPC&oldid=731445841#Implementations).

But since you asked for an embedded compatible framework, I'd suggest you stick with libjson-rpc-cpp, since its the most lightweight framework, where you can [disable certain features](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp#build-from-source) during compilation.

It is also worth mentioning, that I am the author for said framework.

Comment: the documentation of libjson-rpc-cpp is a little bit overwhelming to me as I am new to C++, can you tell me how to quickly integrate this in a c++ project with just the server where I just register the RPC functions and get it running?